What is this seemingly common sounding chord progression?
I'm playing along to Liam Gallagher's I've All I Need on my acoustic, and the chords are
(capo 1st) A7sus - Cmadd9 - G (it "resolves" at the G)
I feel like I hear very similar "resolutions" or chord progressions all the time, so I'm curious to know what this is called.

In English at least, chord progressions don't always have names. A few of them do, but mostly we just call it by what the chords are. In this case, we might say the progression is called "A7sus - Cmadd9 - G", or if G is the key, we might call it a II-IV-I progression (simplifying things). Is that what you're looking for?

There are many very close cadences like this - C>Cm>G, C F9>G, Am>Cm>G, Cm>Ab7>G, Called without special names. The last is often tts. The closest we get is plagal (IV>I or iv>I) but that's about it. If it's Gallagher, he's probably messed around with chords (unknown) that work together in sequence.

@Tim What's "tts"?

@Divizna - tts? tritone substitution.

@ToddWilcox that is kind of what i was looking for. I know you said you were simplifying things - but why is it simply a II-IV-I progression? Wouldn't Am be the II on the key of G, and similarly wouldn't C be the IV? Is it just a case of this being a progression that can't be written in that form?

I don’t understand your comment. “…can’t be written in that form” What form? If you’re looking for the Roman numerals that represent a chord progression, then we don’t answer those kinds of questions here because it would be silly and unhelpful. We would answer a question like “how can I determine the Roman numerals for a chord progression?” Because that would help anyone analyze any chords and increase their understanding of music theory.

As explained in the comments there are lots of such resolutions and they don't have special names. In terms of Roman numerals writing II-IV-I simplifies things because it does not specify the dominant 7th or sus4 on the A, or the minor (and add9) for the C.
ii-V-I is very common and even that does not have a special name: Wikipedia. In G that's Am D G so perhaps the Cm add9 works here as a substitute for a D7.
Since the A7sus is not a minor but the C is, we could write II-iv-I. What makes this a bit different is the inclusion of the D in every chord. It is very common in pop music to spice up simple chords by droning a note - keeping it in all the time - often on an open string.
There are a few reasons why you may find it sounding familiar. It’s possible that you’ve heard this resolution somewhere else but I don’t believe it is as common as as the C-Cm-G resolution mentioned by Tim (which is quite common and to my ears ’schmaltzy’). This one actually sounds a bit like it. Bear in mind that resolutions have a certain function in common - to resolve to the I chord - so in some sense they all sound the same and hence familiar.
However, I think there are a couple of other things going on here. The task that a pop musician is faced with is to be popular (that drives the sales) and the way it’s done is by balancing freshness with familiarity. Using standard chord patterns is a part of familiarity and changing the chords a bit makes things fresh. If I was to use this in a song, I’d play it like this:

Now analysing this in terms of chords does not quite capture what is going on here. Pop music uses two devices which work. I’ve mentioned drones and here we have a G5 chord droning away on the first three strings (in fact just playing the G chord over and over while the melody comes to an end is also a kind of resolution). To make this more interesting, descents are added to the drone. Descents are very familiar in lots of songs (’60’s examples: Beatles: Michelle, While My Guitar Gently Weeps, Dear Prudence, Dylan: It’s All Right Ma, Ballad of a Thin Man, Neil Young: Needle and the Damage Done, etc.) and what we have here are nice descents on the lower strings E-Eb-D and (D)-C-B and A-(-)-G. Bit too much of a good thing perhaps, but that’s the way I hear it.
In my experience the way that these ‘exotic’ changes are arrived at is by noodling with an open mind and an attentive ear. Enjoy strumming!
